# How can I store Laravel-provided access tokens securely?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, cookies, bearer-token

I have a Laravel project that uses Laravel Sanctum to generate access tokens for users.

I return the token to the front-end on a login and sign up request.

Previously, I'd use Laravel's `session()` function to store tokens like so:

```php
session(['token', $accessToken]);
```

But I've been told this is not secure. So now I return it to the front-end (vanilla Javascript) and store it in a cookie. But I'm also being told that's not secure.

Can someone please guide me on where and how exactly I should store the token?

I've heard about setting a `httpOnly` flag, but nowhere actually telling me where to store the token.

Comment: Server side session would be more secure than a client side cookie, that's for sure. Who told you the session wasn't secure, and in what situation did they say it was vulnerable exactly?

Comment: @ADyson - I read online that storing it using Laravel's `session()` makes it vulnerable to session hijacking attacks. Something along those lines

Comment: There are such things of course, but it's not common unless you have other security flaws in your site. Generally, Session is considered to be secure for most purposes, unless the data is very sensitive.

Comment: @ADyson - Yeah, very tempted to just keep using `session()` , think I'm just very paranoid haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store them in the session like you said in your post.

```php
session(['token' => $accessToken]);
```

As long as you are using TLS (HTTPS) this will be safe in the majority of situations.

> `session()` makes it vulnerable to session hijacking attacks.

This is a whole different issue that is not really related to the session itself. People can try to guess the session ID etc. Laravel uses random, long session ID's that are stored in an encrypted cookie. Unless your application has a major security flaw, you shouldn't have to worry about it.

Sure, you could copy a session cookie to a different browser, but this is just how sessions work.

If you want to be really sure that the session was not hijacked:

1. Store the IP-address and User-Agent of the browser that the session was started in.
2. On every request, check whether it matches the current IP-address and User-Agent of the request.
3. If they do not match, you should log the user out and ask to authenticate again.

Answer (score 1):

**FYK**

My personal opinion is, If you're using cookies to use with `httponly` and `secure`

**httpOnly**
It means the cookie can't be accessed by JavaScript

**secure**
To protect against MITM, set the secure flag for the cookie

```
$minutes = 60;
$cookie = cookie('token', $accessToken, $minutes, null, null, true, true); 
return response('cookie')->cookie($cookie);
```

---

> Note: I saw in an article it mentioned `withSameSite('strict')` but not sure if it's for `cookies` or `sessions`. (ex: `$cookie->withSameSite('strict')` as I remember)

Comment: How would a user access this for future requests?

Comment: When you save the token in a cookie, it's automatically included by the browser in every future request to the server. You don't need to manually add the token to each request. In Server side `$token = $request->cookie('token');` will works

Comment: Ahhhhhh this makes sense, I feel stupid.

Comment: @UndercoverCoder as *ADyson* mentioned, the session is also secured. Otherwise, there are more junior hackers to perform session hijacking. But frameworks like laravel are very less for these vulnerabilities. Update the framework to the latest and you're good to go

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to store token if you are using laravel Sanctum package, when you install and migrate it will create personal_access_tokens table where all users token has been stored. Typical usage is like when use login you can generate to

```
return $this->success([
        'token' => auth()->user()->createToken('API Token')->plainTextToken
    ]);
```

and on signout you can destroy the token like that

```
auth()->user()->tokens()->delete()
```

you not need to store token in session or cookie as it's risky

Comment: How would a user access this token for future requests?

Comment: User needs to store this token somewhere or you can provide one endpoint where the user can access its generated token

Answer (score 0):

You should not be storing the token at all, especially the plain text token, if you are using Sanctum. After you login-in your user you create a token for them and send back the plan text token to the user. Than the user uses that token for every subsequent request.

If you need to retrieve the token on your backend you can do `auth()->user()->currentAccessToken()`

Comment: Apologies, by storing I mean when the token is returned to the front-end. For the front-end to use that token for every other request, it needs to store it somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Use Local storage to store your access tokens
Skype also use local storage to store access token